# ESP32 Dual Core

Tags: esp32, programming, function, programming-loop, multicore

Does anyone have experience with using the second ESP32 core? I searched the internet but I only came across two loops that run independently of each other. I would need to be able to call a function from the main loop at a certain moment that would run on the second core and also to be able to put parameters into it that would return the modified ones.

I created a loop2 that runs on core 0 and in this loop the encoder should be checked to update the variables. But for some reason it has a problem with the function as5600.getCumulativePosition() which gets the value from the encoder. This error pops up: Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception) and then ESP reboots. Do someone know how to fix that ?

code:

```
void loop2 (void* pvParameters) {
  while (1)
  {
   
    Serial.println(page);

    while (page == 1)
    {

    Serial.print (" World from loop2() at ");
    Serial.println(xPortGetCoreID());

   
   
   
    //in this part I check the encoder again
    //if it moves to the right: counter++
    //if it moves left: counter--
   
     
     if(as5600.getCumulativePosition()>(angle_in+100))
      {
        //as5600.resetCumulativePosition();
        angle_in = as5600.getCumulativePosition();
        if((counter <6)&&(counter >= 0))//this is the range in which the encoder moves, or the number of elements in the menu
        {
        digitalWrite(BLA,HIGH);
        Serial.print("shipping:");
        //Serial.println(angle_in);
        Serial.println(c1);
        pastTime = millis();
        e=0;
        encoder = 1;
        counter++;
        //variable j and variable i provide screen scrolling
        if((counter==5)&&(j==0))
        {
          j-=12;
          i-=15;
        }
        if((counter==6)&&(j==-12))
        {
          j-=12;
        }
       
        }
      }
     
      if(as5600.getCumulativePosition()<(angle_in-100))
      {
        //as5600.resetCumulativePosition();
        angle_in = as5600.getCumulativePosition();
        if((counter > 0)&&(counter <= 6))//this is the range in which the encoder moves, or the number of elements in the menu
        {
        digitalWrite(BLA,HIGH);
        Serial.print("left:");
        //Serial.println(angle_in);
        Serial.println(c1);
        pastTime = millis();
        e=0;
        encoder = 1;
        counter--;
        if((counter==1)&&(j==-24))
        {
          j+=12;
        }
        if(counter==0)
        {
          i=0;
          j = 0;
        }
        }
      }
   
   

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you look into things more general than just ESP32; look up general multi-threaded programming techniques. It gets pretty complicated.

Comment: @Kabl62, It sounds like all you want is to have a single main thread running that can start a second thread that is running on a separate core and wait for the results. Or, without waiting at the current moment but where it can wait when it is ready for the results. This seems like the exact same thing as an asynchronous task on .NET. But what you really need, depends. You need to provide very fine details about your goals because there are a number of options, spanning from ***extremely easy and simple*** to ***fairly complex***. And which to use depends on what you are on about, in detail.

Comment: @Kabl62, You may not even require the 2nd core. If not, that simplifies things a bit because there will only be one instruction executing at any given moment. So you don't have to deal with simultaneous execution of instructions competing for the same stored value, for example. Special instructions are involved when multi-cores execute simultaneously -- for example `load reserved` and `store conditional` in the RISC-V architecture. And this compounds in crazy ways when you have multichips, each with multicores, populating multiple buses connected via TPAs [Intel term.]

Comment: @Kabl62, Perhaps the most important question to ask and answer is this one: ***"Is your main thread going to sit and wait for the results of the second thread?"*** (That's just a co-routine, if so.) Or put another way, ***"Is the thread call synchronous or asynchronous?"***

Comment: The cores are managed by FreeRTOS. As Hearth suggests,  read up on the required concepts and techniques. Conceptually you can do what you suggest, but probably not quite the way you anticipate., so with some learning you’ll be better equipped to make a better design decision. Consider how you would manage splitting a task between two people such that they don’t step on each other’s toes but yet complete the task efficiently. TLDR you can tell FreeRTOS which core you want to spawn a task on. If you’re using Arduino, FreeRTOS is there silently in the background on the ESP32.

Comment: What environment/language are you using on the ESP32? E.g pure ESP-IDF with C, Arduino, micropython….?

Comment: the point is that I have a loop in which values are written to the display. In that loop there is a separate while loop in which I monitor the status of the encoder. when I notice that the encoder has moved, I jump out of the loop, write out the values and come back again. but the problem is that if I move the encoder too quickly, the encoder loses a few steps and only moves as many places as it managed to record.

Comment: that's why I was just thinking that I would do the loop where the status of the encoder is checked on the second core. So on the first core only the values would be written on the display and on the second the status of the encoder would be checked and it would return the value of the position of the encoder. so the first loop would wait for the value returned by the function on the second core. However, the function that checks the status of the encoder would no longer have to wait for the values to be written out. Or is there aby other option to do this much easier?

Comment: @Kabl62 Can you arrange the hardware so that it interrupts your code whenever the encoder needs to be examined? (It changes.) Or do you have to poll the encoder every so often in order to keep up with it?